# Cplex(number of decimal)

Tags: cplex, ilog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVQSp.png)hi, how can I increase the number of digits
after the comma (number of decimal) in CPLEX for objectif fonction?

thank you
cordially?

Comment: Which api do you use ?

Comment: CPLEX Studio IDE  12.7

Answer (score 1):

You could read this CPLEX technote:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21615825

I gave the example

```
float f = sqrt(2);
execute {
function formatFloat_prec8 (f) {
f = Math.round(f*100000000);
var fs = f.toString();
fs = fs.substring(0,fs.length-8)+','+fs.substring(fs.length-8,fs.length);
return fs;
}
writeln(formatFloat_prec8(f));
};
```

which gives

```
1,41421356
```

at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=8522d33e-966a-4ac3-9b88-4ae8df46d5c7&ps=25

Comment: but I want augmenter decimal number of this function objective for more precision. As shown in the picture down.

Comment: Then have a look at the statistics tab https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/gsoplide/topics/opl_ide_gs_tut_output_tabs.html#gsoplide.uss_ide_gettingstarted.1044796__gsoplide.uss_ide_gettingstarted.1044936

Comment: please sir. can you explian me  this answer you could try to use the setting IloCplex::Param::Emphasis::Numerical???? where i can find the setting??

Comment: "Emphasizes precision in numerically unstable or difficult problems. This parameter lets you specify to CPLEX that it should emphasize precision in numerically difficult or unstable problems, with consequent performance trade-offs in time and memory". This setting is not about display

Comment: exactlty sir, this is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[precision decimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1R2U.png)

I want augment precision decimal.