# cplex, Is there a way to increase the precision in objective function?

Tags: decimal, precision, cplex, ilog

I implemented my mathematical model using Ilog Cplex ver 2.7. the decimal part of the objective function is very small and cplex returns 0 so the cplex abandons part of the objective function (so the objective function is not really optimized). Is there a way to increase the accuracy so that the cplex takes the max of decimal into account?
I have created a file ops to change the decimal prision from 4 to 10 but cplex always does not take into account the figures after the decimal point for you well understands to see the image below.?

[image]

Comment: similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849876/cplexnumber-of-decimal/54875841#54875841

Answer (score 1):

In that part you cannot change the display precision. But as said [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849876/cplexnumber-of-decimal/54875841#54875841) you may see more in the statistics tab.

Or you may use scripting to get any precision you need.

Comment: How I can use scripting to get precision?  the cplex does not really minimize the objective function when we have decimal tea very small.